# How to consider only last 7 quarter data on a rolling basis when I have data in "2021 - Q 4" format in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I need to consider only last 7 quarter data on a rolling basis when I have data in "2021 - Q 4" format
I am not able to do this as we do not have any other date in the table ,please suggest or help me with this,

```
shipped_planned_fiscal_quarter
2021 - Q 4
2021 - Q 2
2022 - Q 4
2021 - Q 2
2022 - Q 3
2021 - Q 2
```

Thanks in advance

a solution or a suggestion for the above problem

Comment: SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products. Which one are you actually using and which version? SQL Server 2008 is 14 years old and out of support for several years. Some of the functions that would make this easier were introduced in SQL Server 2014

Comment: Date reporting becomes a LOT easier if you use [a Calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/), a table prepopulated with eg 10-20 years worth of dates with precalculated fields for year, quarter, month, day of month, week number, week day, etc. You can create a calendar table with a quarter lable column matching the data table's format. After that you can select the last 7 quarters from the Calendar and join them on the quarter label with the data.

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: Why did you use the `mysql` tag then? These are two completely different products. Which version are you using? Many useful ranking functions were added in SQL Server 2014

Comment: I am using SSMS-v18.12.1

Comment: SSMS is SQL Server Management Studio, a client application that's used to connect to and manage SQL Server instances. If you don't know which version of SQL Server you're connecting to you can execute the query `SELECT @@VERSION;` to find out.